# Why isn't this rounding up (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, math

the value of the name is `115.5`, but when I run the below code, I get `115`. Why? I thought `Math.round()` rounded up at `.5`. Please help.

```
Math.round(parseInt(document.getElementsByName("prod_Unit_Price_1")[0].value)));
```

Comment: `parseInt` does the rounding here (or truncation for this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer doesn't have a decimal place. When you `parseInt()` you strip out the decimal. Use `parseFloat()` instead

```
Math.round(parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("prod_Unit_Price_1")[0].value)));
```